# 2006 accord power lock wiring question

Tags: honda, accord, wiring, locks

I'm not sure if such a specific question is appropriate here, but: I have a 2006 Honda Accord Coupe EX with nav. and MT. The Power Window  Master switch in the driver's side door is from a 2003 model. I am going to replace it with a new 2006 model switch (the power window stopped working). On pin 21 (white wire) of the 2003 switch, someone has spliced in a wire and ran it out the door (into the under dash fusebox, I presume). What is the purpose of this? (As far as I can tell from the schematics, the white wire from pin 21 should be connected only to the Driver's Door Key Cylinder Switch.) Should I cut the bodged-in wire when installing the 2006 switch?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! This question is completely on topic for the site. TY for asking it!

Comment: Without me being able to see the schematics, I would find when the white wire is supposed to have voltage. Activate it. If it has voltage when it is supposed to, wire the thing according to schematics and see what happens. If something doesn't work when wired to schematics then troubleshoot and make proper repairs.